# Fatal error JRE when using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using pdfBox (v2.0.8) to generate a PDF file. When I use it locally all seems fine, I get my pdf. But when I push it in a docker, I get this fatal error, this is the [hs_err_pid1.log](https://pastebin.com/Ep86sn1Q) :

I don't know where to start searching a fix, I don't understand how to read this file, and since it works locally I can not reproduce the problem.

I suspect here I have some hints but I don't know what to do with this information :

(L. 118)

```
j  org.myproject.services.impl.DntPdfGeneration.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+198
j  org.myproject.services.impl.DntServiceImpl.pdfGeneration(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+6
j  org.myproject.rest.impl.DntResourceImpl.getPdf(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;+6
```

EDIT :

```
public class DntPdfGeneration {

private final JdbcStoreImpl jdbcStoreManager;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DntPdfGeneration.class);

private static final String DNT_SQL_T_TAUX_DATA = "select * from some_table";

@Inject
public DntPdfGeneration(final JdbcStoreImpl jdbcStoreManager) {
    this.jdbcStoreManager = jdbcStoreManager;
}

public String create(String year, String t) {

    final String DNT_SQL_FIRST_LEVEL = "select * from table";

    final String DNT_SQL_SECOND_LEVEL = "select * from table";

    log.debug("Executing query");
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> DNT_SQL_1_DATA = null;

    List<HashMap<String,Object>> DNT_SQL_2_DATA = null;

    List<HashMap<String,Object>> DNT_T_TAUX_DATA = null;

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    try {
        //Execute first sql statement and store data in DNT_SQL_1_DATA
        DNT_SQL_1_DATA = jdbcStoreManager.makeRawRequest(DNT_SQL_FIRST_LEVEL, "SCHEME");

        DNT_SQL_2_DATA = jdbcStoreManager.makeRawRequest(DNT_SQL_SECOND_LEVEL, "SCHEME");

        DNT_T_TAUX_DATA = jdbcStoreManager.makeRawRequest(DNT_SQL_T_TAUX_DATA,"SCHEME");

        String filePath = System.getenv("DNT_DBO_ENV")+"/"+dateFormat.format(date)+"-dnt.pdf";

        log.debug("Generating pdf file : {} ", filePath);

        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##", symbols);

        //Create new page
        PDPage singlePage = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(PDRectangle.A4.getHeight(), PDRectangle.A4.getWidth()));
        document.addPage(singlePage);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, singlePage);

        int j = 1;

        Integer page = 1;

        int occurences = 0;

        //This boolean checks if 
        Boolean controlCot = false;

        Color littleGrey =  new Color(224,224,224);

        if (DNT_SQL_1_DATA.size() > 0) {

            for (int i=0;i<=DNT_SQL_1_DATA.size()-1;i++) {

                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 8);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(760, 25);
                contentStream.showText("PAGE : "+page.toString());      
                contentStream.endText();

                //do more stuff and things ...

            }

            contentStream.close();
            document.save(filePath);
            if (document != null ) {
                document.close();
            }
         }
        return filePath;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        log.error("SQL error : {}",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IO Exeption : {}",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code for DntPdfGeneration.create

Comment: @NicholasSmith I'll try to edit my code to remove any private information because my company it's pretty strict with that, as soon as I finish I'll edit my question and add the code, thanks !

Comment: @NicholasSmith ok I added the main code of this method, hopefully it will help

Comment: it could be a dumb question but I want to ask just to be safe: do the versions of java match between your local machine and on docker?

Comment: @Alp my local java version is (build 1.8.0_131-b12) and the docker one it's (build 1.8.0_131-b11) could that difference be the problem ?

Comment: @Russo I would not risk it. Isn't it easy to have the same version on both sides and give it a try ?

Comment: @Alp I will try this, we have a CI going on in our company so I guess I'll need to ask help for upgrading the verison the docker uses, thanks for the answers !

Comment: The environment variable `DNT_DBO_ENV` is defined?

Comment: @NicholasSmith yes it is, it was one of the first things I checked :/ I also tested the fact that I can indeed read/write on that file. Also the fatal error seems to happend when I do "PDDocument document = new PDDocument();" because the docker enter in fail state just after doing this

Comment: How are you configuring PDFBox, is it set to work in-memory or create a temporary file?  When you call that constructor it tries to allocate memory or open that temp file. I'm thinking either don't have permission to write to the temp location, or maybe it's running out of memory in your docker instance?

Comment: @NicholasSmith that could be it, actually. I don't know how to configure PDFBox, I can't find any documentation talking about a propertie file or an allocation to memory, could you point me a document were I can find that ?

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/io/MemoryUsageSetting.html